# ClassDefNotFound when adding library

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception, libraries

I'm adding libraries for loading animation but whatever library I add im getting ClassDefNotFound exception along with ClassNotFound exception in xml's preview section also getting could not found identifier for context in projectName for tools:context
this is my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
,'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.github.tajchert:WaitingDots:0.4.0'
}
```

I'm using android studio 1.2

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView (Open Class, Show Exception, 
Clear   Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or 
show sample data when shown in the IDE
Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/wang/avi/R$style
```

Comment: Which classes are in the error?

Comment: Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.tajchert.waitingdots.R$styleable

Comment: Is that library available as an AAR since you're wanting resources from it?

Comment: Dont know, have a look https://github.com/tajchert/WaitingDots also tried https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView

Comment: I'm not sure, but the documentation seems to suggest that simple including the one line of gradle dependency should work. You could try to upgrade your Android Studio and Gradle versions

Comment: seems like gradle not downloading library, getting null pointer exception, what additional information should i seek? do i have to add maven? not clear about these things

Comment: could you see if its working at your side? @cricket_007

Comment: Gradle is a Maven alternative, and not just for Android . You shouldn't mix them. If you are getting nullpointerexception, that seems to be better than the error in the question, so update the stacktrace

Comment: its rendering error, could you see if these libraries that I mentioned above are working at your side, it seems that due to older android version and older api level in preview section, not sure, also I will soon update stacktrace